# Apache Reverse Proxy https to http

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, https, mod-proxy

I have an internet-accessible apache server that has SSL enabled and working.
On the local network, there is another server which provides a tomcat app over http.

The apache server reverse proxies the tomcat app. When the apache server is used over http, the tomcat app is correctly proxied, but when using it over https, the tomcat server returns 404 resource not found. So is the https request not translated to http? I would prefer to do it without touching the tomcat config, since that's not my area.

This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName ext-service.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/mycert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/mykey.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/mybundle.crt
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        <Proxy *>
          AddDefaultCharset off
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/empty/
        ProxyPass / http://int-service.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://int-service.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check the logs of the tomcat : it should work, as the 404 is a real code for http and can not be sent if the https is used. There is a lot of options for the Apache Proxy. You maybe need to use them to have a working situation.

Comment: I should have clarified, the 404 error is returned by the tomcat app. It's probably not set up for https, but I don't want to forward the https request, I want to keep communication between apache and tomcat over http.

Answer (score 1):

If the tomcat is set up to use AJP I suggest you to use that.

```
ProxyPass / ajp://int-service.example.com:<ajp_port>/  
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://int-service.example.com:<ajp_port>/
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adapt the tomcat config, there is no way around it. Your apache config looks okay so far, just two things that are off when I compare it with a setup of mine:

- `DocumentRoot` is useless there, you can remove it since you proxy everything.
- `ProxyPreserveHost` should be `On`

The Tomcat on the other hand has to be told that there is a proxy in front of it and that it uses https instead of http.

There should be a configuration file where the connector is specified.

```xml
<Connector port="80"

   <!-- add these lines -->
   scheme="https"
   proxyName="ext-service.example.com"
   proxyPort="443"

   <!-- other options -->
/>
```

After adding these lines the Tomcat knows how the URLs should be generated.